# Using Jquery to check if items have been added to a list by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a list which users can add items to using a drop down of items. I'm tracking user behavior and want to execute a function each time a user ADDS something to this list (not removes it). The list looks like this:

```
<ul class="items-list" id="user-items">
  <li id="newitem1"></li> 
  <li id="newitem2"></li>
</ul>
```

They can add more items to the list with the dropdown, the issue is there are no Jquery selectors for the links to those items, so I am instead trying to detect when items are added to the list.

My attempts so far are:

`var listOfItems = $("#user-items").children()` - I can count how many items are currently in the list. However I can't work out how to check whether the user has added more items. I am new to Jquery and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction here? Thanks

Comment: How do the users add items to the list? Put the code you need to run in that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOMSubtreeModified event and check if new element added to DOM.

```
$("#a").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("list updated");
});
```

**Demo:**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/646/)

Comment: this is depreciated.

Comment: @manikantgautam thank you for the feedback, I have post this answer so that questioner can get some idea and make changes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks  @manikantgautam - this actually has worked really well in my code but I am concerned if it is depreciated - what is the updated way to achieve this? :)

Answer (score 0):

All the values of dropdown can be checked using Jquery .each() before adding new item.

```
<ul class="items-list" id="user-items">
  <li id="newitem1"></li> 
  <li id="newitem2"></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: How does this help the OP know when something has been added? All it does it loop through the existing items and log their text content

Comment: Before adding new element using JavaScript, it can be checked whether that new element is already exist in Output of existing element.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe mutations in that specific part of the DOM and do whatever you want when they occur.

Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Example:

```js
const itemsList = document.querySelector("#user-items");

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      // Do whatever you want here, I'm just logging that
      // a child of the <ul> has been added.
      console.log("A child node has been added");  
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(itemsList, { childList: true, subtree: true });

/**
 * Just some basic code to add items to the list. Not jQuery, but
 * you already have this code I assume, so this is just here to make
 * the demo work
 */
const itemAdder = document.querySelector("#add-item");
let itemNumber = 0;

itemAdder.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  itemNumber++;
  const listItem = document.createElement("LI");
  listItem.setAttribute("id", `user-item-${itemNumber}`);
  const listItemText = document.createTextNode(`List item ${itemNumber}`);
  listItem.appendChild(listItemText);
  itemsList.appendChild(listItem);
});
```

```html
<ul id="user-items">
</ul>

<button id="add-item">Add Item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve so by using `MutationObserver`.The `MutationObserver interface`  provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the `DOM tree` . It is designed as a replacement for the older Mutation Events feature which was part of the `DOM3` Events specification.
here is a working example.

```js
var targetNode = $("#user-items");
function createObserver(callback) {
    return new MutationObserver(function (mutationRecords) {
        mutationRecords.forEach(callback);
    });
}

$("#user-items").each(function () {
    var obs = createObserver(function (mutation) {
        $(mutation.addedNodes).css("background-color", "green");
    });
    obs.observe(this, { childList: true });
});



setTimeout(function(){
  $("#user-items").append('<li id="newitem3">New One</li>');
},1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items-list" id="user-items">
  <li id="newitem1">Old One</li> 
  <li id="newitem2">Old two</li>
</ul>
```